# Airport options for trip to Genoa and Verona

Tags: air-travel, italy, genoa, verona

I am planning a trip to northern Italy. I will start it with two days of Giro d'Italia in and around Genoa and then I will move on to Verona for a javascript conference. I was thinking that flying to Milan (from Sweden) would be the best option and then get around by train. However I just now realized that although Genoa is an hour or so from Milan by train - Verona is more like 4 hours and a stop in Bologna.

Are there any obvious better way to do this than flying to Milan?

UPDATE: I had it wrong about train from Verona to Milan - it is also 1-2 hours. Still it is a bit cumbersome to travel like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mistaken on your journey times, but Milan is still definitely your best bet.

By train, Milan to Genoa is over 4 hours, and Genoa to Verona is over 6 hours.

By road, however, the times are more like 1:30 from Milan to Genoa and 3 hours Genoa to Verona

Why not hire a car for the trip? Driving in northern Italy can be an amazing experience.

Comment: Milan to Genoa is 1h30, not 4. ;)

Comment: Actually I am planning to rent a car for the part when I get from Genoa to Verona. But maybe I should extend it to the whole trip....

Comment: JoE - the best time I could find was over 4. I must have missed something.

Comment: Ended up renting a car.... :-)